# iOS 6 UIDatePicker timer lets user select 0 countDownDuration

Tags: ios, uikit, ios6

I'm using a UIDatePicker in UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer to allow the user to select a duration.

If you set the timer interval to 5 minutes, the user will be able to select 0 hours : 0 minutes (which is bad; this is not allowed in iOS 5 or even in iOS 6 with a 1 minute interval).

Right now I'm fixing it by doing this on change:

```
-(void)timerValueChanged
{
    int clockInterval = workoutTimePicker.minuteInterval * 60;

    if (workoutTimePicker.countDownDuration < clockInterval) {
        workoutTimePicker.countDownDuration = clockInterval;
    }
}
```

But that makes the roller jump.  How can I animate the roller?

Comment: I just ran a quick test (on iPad simulator iOS 6) and it wouldn't let me set the countdown to 0:00... You can briefly select it but it animates back to 0:01 instantly. Are your using the simulator or an actual device?

Comment: Ah, there's one detail which turns out to be important.  You need to set the interval to be 5 minutes.  If you do that, this will happen in both the simulator and the device. (editing question now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no `setCountDownDuration:animated:` so we have to use `setDate:animated:`.

We must create a `NSDate` object with current day/month/year to allow us to fill the minutes component, with your desired value, let's say it's `workoutTimePicker.minuteInterval`:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    components.hour = 0;
    components.minute = workoutTimePicker.minuteInterval; // how much minutes you want
    components.second = 0;
NSDate * resetedMinsDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

So with that new date, we just need to set the picker's date:

```
[workoutTimePicker setDate:resetedMinsDate animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks!  That worked a lot better than the hack I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

While trying out [Carlos Ricardo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/468868/carlos-ricardo)'s answer, I've found out a more concise solution (using swift):

```
let minDate = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()) + clockInterval
datePicker.setDate(minDate, animated: true)
```